# Infinite Auto Scroll ListView with Scroll Speed Controlled

Tags: android, listview, scroll, autoscroll

I have been working on a `ListView`idea where it keeps scrolling automatically with no user interaction and that is absolutely doable using the android APIs for instance ***smoothScrollToPositionFromTop***.

I have implemented `ListView BaseAdapter` where it load items forever (almost) to get a non stopping self repeated `ListView`.

What I want to achieve here is to keep my`ListView`scrolling forever with certain speed (slow) to make items clear and readable while scrolling down, I not sure yet if `ListView` is my best choice here.

below is a snippet of what I am trying to do. the result is good somehow but it's not smooth enough, I can feel the ListView flickers.

I need to improve **smoothness, efficiency and control the speed**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int listViewSize = mListView.getAdapter().getCount();

        for (int index = 0; index < listViewSize ; index++) {
            mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(mListViewA.getLastVisiblePosition() + 100, 0, 6000);
            try {
                // it helps scrolling to stay smooth as possible (by experiment)
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You have achieved this functionality (infinite scrolling) but want to improve smoothness/efficiency/slow it down?

Comment: define "not smooth enough". This could be due to your adapter part, some items may be slow to load.

Comment: @breadbin: updated, njzk2 "not smooth enough" I mean I can see the listview slowing and then scroll again which makes it lagging. I need the scrolling to be one shot and forever.

Comment: I think it's problem in fill listview.just improve the your adapter and use viewHoledr mechanisam to fill listview.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest, thath your adapter implemented in effective way.
so this code is just scrolls listview

you need to try another values of variables

```
final long totalScrollTime = Long.MAX_VALUE; //total scroll time. I think that 300 000 000 years is close enouth to infinity. if not enought you can restart timer in onFinish()

final int scrollPeriod = 20; // every 20 ms scoll will happened. smaller values for smoother

final int heightToScroll = 20; // will be scrolled to 20 px every time. smaller values for smoother scrolling

listView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                new CountDownTimer(totalScrollTime, scrollPeriod ) {
                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        listView.scrollBy(0, heightToScroll);
                                    }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    //you can add code for restarting timer here
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: it seems an elegant solution, I am not at my development machine right now to test it, I will let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: there is no doubt that you deserve the bounty, but there is a concern about the `ListView` in my infinite adapter, when the listview scrollBy it seems `getView(...)` does not get called so I see empty cell after the last cell get scrolled, do I need to invalidate the `ListView` while scrolling?

Comment: I wroted some test app for this http://pastebin.com/9fUTuR1u You were right - scrollBy scrolls Listview in incorrect way. But it worked for me in ScrollView. BTW, if you have a small number of items in list view, you can add more smoothiness to scrolling if you try ScrollView with Linearlayout in it with all your items.

Comment: I will try this on a `ScrollView` but that would defeat the purpose of the endless adapter. what do you think?

Comment: @AhmadTK yes, if you have big number of items (more 15) you MUST use adapter to prevent OOM errors. Did you try my source code in pastebin?

Comment: I wrote time ago this blog post about how to auto scroll a ListView. I hope it helps. It will be easy to control the speed just changing dynamically the amount pixels scroll. http://blog.jpardogo.com/autoscroll-a-listview-with-listviewautoscrollhelper/

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali Just change listView.scrollBy(0, heightToScroll) to listView.scrollListBy(heightToScroll) and it will work with ListView.

Comment: Unfortunately scrollListBy requires API level 19, and i have min sdk set to 11. now what?

Answer (score -1):

Here a few pointers : [Simulate onFling() programmatically instead of detecting it (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836677/simulate-onfling-programmatically-instead-of-detecting-it-android)

and [Programmatically Fling ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214956/programmatically-fling-listview-android)

It's hard to figure out what you call smooth enough in your case. Usually smoothness problems are related to a non optimal usage of listviews and troubles in either cell layouts or view creation / recycling inside the getView method of adapters.

Do you [use a placeholder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) ?
An important thing to consider is also [Drawables usage](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html).

I never achieved what you are looking for, but a simple idea that comes to mind is :

- find a way to scroll the view of 1 position or 2.
- use a ring buffer inside your adapter. For instance let's say you got 100 items in your list of items. Then at the beginning, item 0 of the listview is item 0 of your list. When listview is scrolled up of 1 item, then item 0 of listview should become item 1 in your list. Thus the problem would not be scrolling but more syncing with scrolling and displaying an endless list of items.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the effort answering my question, let's talk about it: **1st** first link uses `InstrumentationTestCase` which I believe I can't use it in my app I mean on a regular Activity (correct me if I am wrong). **2nd** the other link has nothing to do with my problem, I have passed the auto scrolling issue/implementation. **3rd** Yes absolutely I am using place holders. **4th** I have zero concern implementing endless adapter :)

Comment: what about slowing down ListView auto scrolling?

Comment: You could give a try to scrolling by offset instead of positions : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollByOffset(int)

Comment: for the sake of argument let say `scrolling by offset` have worked, how am I going to slow the scrolling speed?

Comment: decrease the pace at which you call this method. no ?