# Ultravisual iPhone app like UI for android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

can anyone explain me how to recreate the scrolling effect in android like below iPhone app and this is not automatic scroll..

[image]

**i have tried the following :**

```
myview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView listViews, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            final View view = getViewByPosition(firstVisibleItem);
}
```

I have no idea how it's made...

Comment: With some modifications in this library..You can achieve that https://github.com/jpardogo/ListBuddies

Comment: thanks @kalyanpvs but you shared the parallel list view example and i want the above effect on the list or view when scrolling can you please give any idea or example..

Comment: may be this will suitable for you ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952357/infinite-auto-scroll-listview-with-scroll-speed-controlled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250470/ultravisual-iphone-app-like-uiview-or-uitableview-scroll can you please read this

Comment: Did you ever this this completed?